# Rails 3 - Deploy Rails application on Windows XP server

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I have to deploy my Rails application on production environment. It is a Windows XP pc =(

I have found this articles http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/5/11/deploying-rails-on-windows-servers

But they are very very old. Is there a newer resource of information?
Any experiences?
Any tips? Apache? Mongrel?

Thanks

Comment: Considering how inexpensive a VPS is, this seems like more trouble than it's worth. I don't think even Microsoft ever called XP a server-grade OS.

Comment: My client is a Bank and his OS is Windows XP (believe it or not). He wants to mantain the application behind his firewall, not in an external hosting.

Comment: That is truly terrifying. Hope you're not there in 2014 when all their XP machines are end-of-lifed and Microsoft stops issuing security updates.

Comment: Yes, thats unbelievable. I have one question, is there any way to setup a linux virtual machine and redirect Windows´ Apache to that server within the VM?

Comment: Apache has a very robust proxy subsystem that could do this called `mod_proxy` that can be configured to relay all traffic to an internal system provided you can specify the IP and port. Most VM systems issue predictable IPs that are maintained between reboots.

Comment: So do you think a solution can be:
- VM with Linux and Rails runnning on passenger 
- Somehow publish the IP of the VM
- Redirect Apache traffic to that VM

right?

Comment: That sounds like a much better plan than trying to jimmy Rails on to an eleven year old OS. You can use something like VirtualBox from Oracle, VMWare, or VirtualPC to manage your virtual machine.

Comment: Ok, I will have to discover how to expose a IP from a VM, but I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

> **Installing Ruby** – The RubyInstaller team has also provided a collection of tutorials from users who have setup a Ruby environment
>   on Windows. Many of these include common issues experienced during the
>   installation process, as well as the steps for setting up Git, MySQL,
>   SQLite3, etc. https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Tutorials
>
> **Setting Up Git** – GitHub has a set of instructions outlining how to setup Git on Windows. http://help.github.com/win-git-installation/
>
> **Rails Tutorials** – Check out the Rails Installation (Windows) video as well as other great resources for learning Rails.
>   http://railstutorial.org/
>
> Finally, join the RubyInstaller Google Group for any additional
>   questions. http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller

source -> http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/ruby-on-windows-the-last-frontier/

Comment: This is useful but it is for development. My development environment is Mac but the production environment is windows.

Comment: What I need is to deploy the already developed Application in Windows XP.

Comment: Im getting the feeling that you might have miss some of the useful articles in https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Tutorials that talk about deploying to Windows.

Comment: Nathan, I am trying to use Mongrel with Apache on Windows. I couldn´t configure it. Do you have any good document about that. I didn´t find in those links

Comment: Do you already have apache running on this windows server? Are there production web apps running? Is apache a requirement?

Comment: Yes, they have production Apps running on that apache. Maybe I dont need to pass through apache. What do you think?

Comment: depends. You see apache is monopolizing port 80. That is leaves you little options other then to use the apache passthrough. 

However, if the windows server is behind a proxy or firewall that allows you to map and forward traffic from one source and port the a destination source and port, then you can make use of nginx, mongrel, webrick or whatever else you would like to use. 

For example let's say that you a domain tonyrailsbro.com pointed to your firewall or proxy. the firewall or proxy would have a rule that says requests to tonyrailsbro.com should route to windows box on port 3000.

Comment: Final thought. If a firewall or proxy is not in the picture, apache itself can do the traffic route to port 3000.